# Java code not working in OSX Mavericks

Tags: java, macos, decode, asn.1

I'm trying to run a java library, so that I can build upon it and do my customization. The library is called jayu parses ASN files so that you can decode them. It can be downloaded [here](https://code.google.com/p/jayu/downloads/list)

There are a few test data to check the library in the "test" folder and mentioned in the Readme.txt file. There is a asn2csv batch file for windows but I'm using OSX mavericks. According to the Readme file, I need to run it by invoking the command:

```
ls $ASN_DATA_DIR/*.dat | xargs java -cp "./*.jar:."  Path/To/Stream1.txt  test.testdata.Stream1 $OUTPUT_DIR
```

OR

```
java -cp "*.jar;$PATH_TO_TEST_DIR" Stream1.txt test.testdata.Stream1  . Path/To/Stream1.dat
```

But whatever I try I always get `Error: Could not find or load main class Stream1.txt`

I'm not a Java programmer. What am I doing wrong here? The development of this seems to be inactive lately but it's still useful. So, I'm posting it here, hoping someone will help me run the example.

Edit: I've added the tree structure of the directory and the files

```
+ jayu
     |--Readme.txt           
     |--commons-compiler.jar
     |--janino.jar
     |--jayu.jar             (ASN parser)
     |--AsnToCsv.bat         (Command line Tool)
     +--test                 (Contains test data for examples)
         |
         + testdata         
              |
              Stream1.txt   (Grammar File)
              Stream1.dat   (ASN Data File)
              Stream1.java  {mapFile}
              ...
```

Comment: You sure you're configuring your args correctly? "Stream1.txt" doesn't look like a class name to me.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I've just followed the instructions in the Readme.txt in jayu_0.4.zip. I've tried putting the Stream1.java as the first arg as well. Didn't work either :).

Comment: Using Stream1.java as the first arg wouldn't be correct.  You need the name of a class, not the name of a file.  But sparc_spread's answer should get you on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

It is interpreting `Stream1.txt` as the Java class you are trying to execute, because it is treating at as your first argument to `java`. Your first argument should be the name of the class containing the `main()`, or, the executable JAR must be indicated with a `-jar` option.

This would seem to indicate that `"*.jar;$PATH_TO_TEST_DIR"` is evaluating to blank.  Can you see if there are any `.jar` files in your current working directory?  Also what is the value of `$PATH_TO_TEST_DIR`?

Another thing is that if you use the second form on OS X, you should have a `:` instead of a `;` because it is a Unix-based OS, not Windows.

---

### Update1

I had a slight error with my description of how to run an executable JAR.  You use the `-jar` option, not `-cp` (I corrected it above).  Since they put `-cp` in their invocation, I'm guessing they are not intending to target the executable JAR, but rather to name the main class.  That to me says that `test.testdata.Stream1` is that main class, which means the ordering they gave you is wrong.  Try this:

`java -cp "*.jar:$PATH_TO_TEST_DIR" test.testdata.Stream1 Stream1.txt   . Path/To/Stream1.dat`

or some other ordering that starts with:

`java -cp "*.jar:$PATH_TO_TEST_DIR" test.testdata.Stream1 ..........`

That is, that makes `test.testdata.Stream1` the very first command line argument to `java`.

Comment: I've added the folder structure to the question. I'm running the code from the topmost jayu/ folder. So, $PATH_TO_TEST_DIR is test/testdata where the java file resides. But according to the instructions the Stream1.txt is the first argument. You're right, somehow the jar aren't being read from the classpath. I've also tried using : instead of ;, no luck.

Comment: In the `asn2csv.bat`, is there a relatively legible line where `java` is invoked? If so can you post it in the question?

Comment: Assuredly, Stream1.txt should not be the first argument.  You may have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BGBCIEFC for an explanation of the arguments to "java".  The general form is java [options] classname [args], where [options] are options to java itself (e.g. -cp) and [args] are the arguments to pass to the Java class that implements main().